# How to process geometry vertices from SCNSkinner on the CPU to get actual position of each vertices?

Tags: swift, scenekit, skinning

I have found some sources on that, one of them is from Rajawali framework

```
"mat4 TransformedMatrix = (vBoneWeight1.x * uBoneMatrix[int(vBoneIndex1.x)]) + \n"
        + "(vBoneWeight1.y * uBoneMatrix[int(vBoneIndex1.y)]) + \n"
        + "(vBoneWeight1.z * uBoneMatrix[int(vBoneIndex1.z)]) + \n"
        + "(vBoneWeight1.w * uBoneMatrix[int(vBoneIndex1.w)]);\n"
        +

        "   gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * TransformedMatrix * position;\n"
```

to blend bones transform on GPU
but i can't find how to adjust this code to work with SceneKit
i can read weights, nodes, and indices, but what matrixes should i use?